# Css selectors what is faster

Tags: css, performance, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's better in CSS: div.something or just .something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556241/whats-better-in-css-div-something-or-just-something)

Can you please provide me with answers and maybe some explanations on this question.

What is faster in css?

```
.someClass
```

or

```
div.someClass
```

Comment: my guess would be `div.someClass` as it seems more specific than the former

Answer (score 3):

The former is faster for the browser to render.

Google has a great article on this.

[Optimize browser rendering](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering)