# Css rules - which one is faster

Tags: css, performance, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed of CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536091/speed-of-css)

Let's say I have this Html markup:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, I have four Css rules:

```
.c {}

div.c {}

.a .b .c {}

div.a div.b div.c {}
```

Now... which Css rule is the fastest? In my oppinion, it goes from the slowest to the fastest. Am I correct? Here's how I think: the more exact the Css rule gets, the faster browser finds all the suiting elements. Correct? If not, why?

Comment: You should worry more about being *specific*. :)

Comment: @Crashworks Given the proliferation of browsers, this isn’t really a helpful answer, especially since other people have already done the tedious (and not entirely trivial) work of writing comprehensive, precise benchmarks which can be referred to.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. However, thank you for the "link". I found it very useful ;)